# Qt Creator issue : Cannot open include file: ‘windows.h’

Tags: qt, installation, qt-creator

I have installed ‘Qt Creator 2.4.1 Based on Qt 4.7.4 (32 bit)’ on Windows 7 with Visual studio 2008. But on creating the basic project am getting following error :

```
 c:\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008\..\win32-msvc2005\qplatformdefs.h:67: 
error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
```

Also I checked the windows.h its present in following location : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\

I would like to mention that I can’t use the MinGW target due to project specifications.

Requesting everyone to help me out of this situation.

Comment: Try providing the complete path to the Header file "window.h"

Answer (score 1):

in Qt Creator, Tools--Options, Build&Run, Kits, choose a kit and edit its attributes, change the Compiler from "Microsoft Windows SDK ..." to "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 9.0 (x86)".

I solved the same problem by this way.

Answer (score 0):

Check **Qt creator's Projects/Build Environment** and **edit variables**

```
(INCLUDE, LIB, OSINCLUDES, OSLIBRARIES, PROGRAMFILES, SDKDIR, SDKTOOLS, WINDOWSSDKDIR)
```

that contains Windows SDK 7.1 path(**C:\Program Files **(x86)**\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1**).

Maybe Windows SDK 7.1 is installed at **"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1"**